# Retrieval of synonyms of an instance from whole ontology

Tags: java, owl, ontology, apache-jena

```
Individual ind = model.createIndividual("http://www.semanticweb.org/ontologies/Word#Human", isSynonymOf);

    System.out.println( "Synonyms of given instance are:" );

   StmtIterator it =ind.listProperties(isSynonymOf);
    while( it.hasNext() ) {
      Statement stmt = ((StmtIterator) it).nextStatement();
      System.out.println( " * "+stmt.getObject());
    }
```

Output

```
Synonyms of given instance are:

  http://www.semanticweb.org/ontologies/Word#Human
  http://www.semanticweb.org//ontologies/Word#Mortal
  http://www.semanticweb.org/ontologies/Word#Person
```

Problem 1: My output shows whole URI but I need output as under

```
 Synonyms of given instance are:
 Human
 Mortal
 Person
```

Problem 2: I have 26 instances and every time I have to mention its URI to show its synonyms. How will I show synonyms of any instance from whole ontology *model* instead of mentioning URIs again and again. I am using eclipse Mars 2.0 and Jena API

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. You can use REGEX or simply Java string operations to extract the substring after `#`. Note, best practice is to provide human readable representations of URIs and not to encode it in the URI. For instance, `rdfs:label` is a common property for doing that.
2. It is simply iterating over all individuals of the ontology which are returned by

   `model.listIndividuals()`

Some comments:

- You're using the method `createIndividual` not as expected. The second argument denotes a class and you're giving it a property. Please use [Javadoc](https://jena.apache.org/documentation/javadoc/jena/org/apache/jena/ontology/OntModel.html#createIndividual-java.lang.String-org.apache.jena.rdf.model.Resource-) for the future.
- I don't understand why you're casting `it` to `StmtIterator` - that doesn't make sense
- Using `listPropertiesValues` is more convenient since you're only interested in the values.
- Use Java 8 to make the code more compact

```
model.listIndividuals().forEachRemaining(ind -> {
    System.out.println("Synonyms of instance " + ind + " are:");
    ind.listPropertyValues(isSynonymOf).forEachRemaining(val -> {
        System.out.println(" * " + val);
    });
});
```

Java 6 compatible version:

```
ExtendedIterator<Individual> indIter = model.listIndividuals();
while(indIter.hasNext()) {
    Individual ind = indIter.next();
    System.out.println("Synonyms of instance " + ind + " are:");
    NodeIterator valueIter = ind.listPropertyValues(isSynonymOf);
    while(valueIter.hasNext()) {
        RDFNode val = valueIter.next();
        System.out.println(" * " + val);
    }
}
```

Comment: when i use java 8 the above code works well. But i have constraint of java 6. the Lamda expression do not work in java 6. I have to use java 6.  How to make above code for java 6 ??

Comment: `model.listIndividuals()` returns an iterator. Just use it as usual. `ind.listPropertyValues(isSynonymOf)` returns an iterator as well.

Comment: Thank you. I did not uderstand it  correctly. Please reflect it on above code.

Comment: Shouldn't you know how to use an iterator in Java? I mean it's pretty basic. `ExtendedIterator<Individual> it = model.listIndividuals(); while(it.hasNext()) {...`

Comment: I don't understand what is now so difficult to replace both usages of `forEachRemaining` with an iterator. I told you that `model.listIndividuals()` returns an iterator of individuals. And for each such individual `ind` you call the method `ind.listPropertyValues(isSynonymOf)` which also returns an iterator, this time of nodes.

Comment: Sorry, but I really don't understand the problem. It is so basic Java stuff...I updated my answer. Please learn Java programming and read the Jena documentation next time. And using Java 6 nowadays is really strange to be honest.